# How to send A and B messages at the same time?

Tags: abtesting

When doing an AB test on two groups of 7k contacts, what seem to happen is that first the A group is sent in full, then the B group is processed.

It obviously means that the second group is going to be sent later (in the latest experiment, 30 min later) than the first one, so obviously, it's a huge bias and it's hardly possible to compare the open or click rates, because A has such a head start.

Is this possible to change the way the mails are sent to process the two groups as the same time? ie. change something on the cronjob?

Comment: We've also run in to this issue. Even when using multiple 'send' processes - CiviCRM still sends all the A batches and then starts on the B batches. This is perhaps something to raise in the issue queue? Since it sort of defeats the object of an A/B test.

Comment: I did open an issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was to keep big batches (bigger than the test groups) and allow to run several jobs, and then:

```
drupal_root=/var/www/drupal

*/5 * * * * www-data nice -n19 /usr/bin/drush -u 1 -r $drupal_root civicrm-api job.process_mailing auth=0 -y -l wemove
*/5 * * * * www-data nice -n19 /usr/bin/drush -u 1 -r $drupal_root civicrm-api job.process_mailing auth=0 -y -l wemove
```

Comment: This is still not solving the problem 100%: if one of the processor, is busy processing another mailing, A and B will still be sent at different time

Comment: Has this been resolved yet?

Comment: Still not perfect. The ultimate plan is to move so the AB are part of the same mailing. Part of mosaico next version... and still looking for financial help to make it happen. Could you help?

Comment: I'm not clear as to why AB testing functionality has to be bound up with mosaico. If there are details somewhere about what financial help is needed and what work needs to be done that would help if I'm approaching clients who may be interested in getting AB testing working properly.

Comment: Basically, to be sure A and B are sent at the same time, it needs to be a single mailing, hence change of UI... and it's better to build on the top of mosaico for that ;) More information: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/ABn+testing+v2